# Commutative diagram with a local $k$-algebra morphism on spaces with functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. By $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ space with functions I mean $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf of some continuous $k$-valued functions closed under inverse.

Let $(X, \mathcal{O}_X), (Y, \mathcal{O}_Y)$ be spaces with functions , and suppose $\psi: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $\phi: \mathcal{O}_Y \rightarrow \psi_* \mathcal{O}_X$ is a sheaf morphism such that at the level of germs $\phi_{\psi(x)}$ is a local $k$-algebra morphism. In trying to prove that $\phi$ is just composition with $\psi$, I'm stuck at seeing why exactly it is that the diagram commutes:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathcal{O}_{Y, \psi(x)} @> \phi_{\psi(x)} >> \mathcal{O}_{X, x}\\
    @V  V V= @VV  V\\
     k @>>id> k 
\end{CD}
where the vertical arrows are given by
$$\mathcal{O}_{Y, \psi(x)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Y, \psi(x)}/m \rightarrow k,$$
$$f_{\psi(x)} \mapsto f_{\psi(x)} \mod m \mapsto f(\psi(x)) \ (f \textrm{ a representative of } f_{\psi(x)} ), $$ where $m$ is the maximal ideal of germs canceling at $\psi(x)$ and similarly for $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$.

I don't know if I'm wrong about this, but there doesn't seem to me to be a canonical way in which $k$ embeds into $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$; of course, modulo $m$, for any $a \in k$ there is only one germ at $x$ taking the value $a$ - however, wouldn't giving an embedding explicitly also require choosing for each $a$ in $k$ an element of $m$?

If this is the case, how can I actually check the commutativity on an element-wise basis?

Comment: There is a very canonical embedding, namely the germs of the constant functions.